# mix sound over network from multiple devices to a single output

Tags: mixing, windows, networking, android

I have two computers (windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04) and an android phone (nexus 5 lollipop)  Is there software out there that will mix the audio from all of my devices so all sounds will play on a single set of headphones?  It seems like this should be possible over the network somehow.

Comment: If you don't mind getting your coding hands dirty, PulseAudio may be a starting point: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/

Answer (score 1):

Doubt you could do this over a network, and it certainly wouldn't be easy, especially when the phone comes into play.  However, using any basic hardware sound mixer, you could take the output from the three headphone jacks on your three devices, mix them to taste, and listen over your headphones.

[http://www.amazon.com/Mackie-802-VLZ3-8-Ch-Compact-Recording/dp/B00132EJKG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00132EJKG)

Comment: hmm that looks pretty fancy. I think PulseAudio will work but it will take a lot of configuration to get it there. 

This may be an opportunity to write a mobile app. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio